# Congruence between powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove this result which arises when trying to solve certain congruence equations:

> Let $a$ and $n$ be prime numbers and $x$ and $y$ integers such that
> $a^x \equiv a^y\pmod n$. Then $ x\equiv y  \pmod {n-1}$.

I guess more general result would not have to make so many assumptions but these work fine for my purposes. Any ideas how to get started? I have tried to show this for hours now without any progress.

Comment: First, you require $a$ and $n$ to be *distinct* prime numbers since, otherwise, $a = n$ gives $a \equiv a^2 \pmod{n}$. Second, $x \equiv y \pmod{n-1}$ is not always true, e.g., it's not true for $2^1 \equiv 2^4 \pmod{7}$. Instead, what is true is that, for any *coprime* $a$ and $n$, with $a^x \equiv a^y \pmod{n}$, then $x \equiv y \pmod{m}$ where $m$ is the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $a$ modulo $n$, i.e., $m = \operatorname{ord}_n(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

The result you are trying to prove is false. A counterexample is given by $a=7$ and $n=3$, with $x=1$ and $y=2$.